# Z-axis Scale in 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d, tikz-3dplot

I am recreating this graph.

[image]

I can't quite figure out how to scale the z-axis to look like this.

This is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning, angles, quotes, arrows.meta, decorations.pathreplacing,calligraphy,backgrounds, decorations.markings, bending}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{cutwin}
\usepackage{tzplot}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
    
\pgfplotsset{
        every non boxed x axis/.style={
            xtick align=center,
            tick style={line width=0.5pt, color=black},
            x axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=0.5pt},
            xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=mid},
            xlabel=$x$
        },
         every non boxed y axis/.style={
            ytick align=center,
            tick style={line width=0.7pt, color=black},
            y axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=0.5pt},
            ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=mid},
            ylabel=$y$
        },
        every non boxed z axis/.style={
            ztick align=center,
            tick style={line width=0.5pt, color=black},
            z axis line style={{Latex[width=1.5mm]}-{Latex[width=1.5mm]},black,line width=0.5pt},
            zlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)}, anchor=mid},
            zlabel=$z$
        },
        tick label style={
            font=\tiny,
        }
    }       
    \definecolor{blue1}{RGB}{66, 127, 187}
    \definecolor{purple1}{RGB}{177, 15, 189}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis on top, xmin=-3,xmax=3,ymin=-3,ymax=3,zmin=-2,zmax=4,axis lines=center,view/v=45,view/h=45,scale=2,xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2}, ytick={-2,-1,0,1,2},ztick={-1,0,1,2,3}]
        \fill[gray,opacity=0.45] (-2.5,-2.5,0) -- (-2.5,2.5,0) -- (2.5,2.5,0) -- (2.5,-2.5,0) -- cycle;
        \fill[blue1,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,2) -- (1,2,3) -- cycle;
        \fill[purple1,opacity=0.5] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,2) -- (-2,0,1);
        \draw[red, dashed, line width=0.5pt] (1,0,0) -- (1,2,0);
        \draw[red, dashed, line width=0.5pt] (1,2,0) -- (0,2,0);
        \draw[red, dashed, line width=0.5pt] (1,2,0) -- (1,2,3);
        \fill[black] (1,2,3) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        \draw[red, dashed, line width=0.5pt] (0,1,0) -- (0,1,2);
        \draw[red, dashed, line width=0.5pt] (-2,0,0) -- (-2,0,1);
        \draw[-{Latex[width=1.5mm]}, line width=1.5pt] (0,0,0) -- (0,1,2);
        \draw[-{Latex[width=1.5mm]}, line width=1.5pt] (0,0,0) -- (1,2,3);
        \fill[black] (0,1,2) circle [radius=2.5pt];
        \draw[-{Latex[width=1.5mm]}, line width=1.5pt] (0,0,0) -- (-2,0,1);
        \fill[black] (-2,0,1) circle [radius=2.5pt];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a suggestion, but perhaps Ti*k*Z is better than PGFPlots for this graph?

You can solve your problem using an `isometric view` form the `perspective` library. The rest is easier in Ti*k*Z save for the ticks, but you can use a `\pic` for that task.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

% colors, styles and a \pic for the tikcs
\definecolor{blue1}  {RGB}{066,127,187}
\definecolor{purple1}{RGB}{177,015,189}
\tikzset
{
  point/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0.4mm},
  pics/tick/.style=
  {
    /tikz/transform shape,
    code=
    {
      \draw (0.05,0) --++ (-0.1,0);
      \draw (0,0.05) --++ (0,-0.1) node[pos=3,transform shape=false] {$#1\ifnum#1<0\phantom{-}\fi$};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,isometric view,rotate around z=-90,line join=round]
% coordinates
\coordinate (O) at  (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A) at  (1,2,3);
\coordinate (B) at  (0,1,2);
\coordinate (C) at (-2,0,1);
% plane
\fill[gray,opacity=0.45,canvas is xy plane at z=0] (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
% axes
\draw[latex-latex] (-2.8,0,0) -- (2.8,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-2.8,0) -- (0,2.8,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[latex-latex] (0,0,-1.8) -- (0,0,3.8) node[above] {$z$};
% red dashed lines
\draw[red,dashed] (1,2,0) -- (A);
\draw[canvas is xy plane at z=0,red,dashed]  (1,0) |- (0,2);
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x=0,red,dashed]  (1,0) |- (0,2);
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y=0,red,dashed] (-2,0) |- (0,1);
% ticks
\foreach\i in {-2,-1,1,2}
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\j{\i==-1?\i+2:\i+1}
  \pic[canvas is xy plane at z=\j] {tick=\j};
  \pic[canvas is xz plane at y=\i] {tick=\i};
  \pic[canvas is yz plane at x=\i] {tick=\i};
}
% triangles
\fill[blue1  ,opacity=0.5] (A) -- (O) -- (B);
\fill[purple1,opacity=0.5] (C) -- (O) -- (B);
% vectors with points
\foreach\i in {A,B,C}
  \draw[thick,-latex] (O) -- (\i) node[point] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]